# Generate UniqueIdentifier GUID in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

I am using a GUID for a batch identifier in SSIS.  My final output goes to SQL Server.

I know how I can generate one using `Select NewId() MyUniqueIdentifier` in Sql Server - I can generate one using a query and an Execute SQL task.

I am however looking to do this within a SSIS package if possible without SQL Server available.

Can I generate a GUID within SSIS?

Comment: do you want to load it to new table, if yes do have data in that table

Comment: You could do this is a derived column     (DT_GUID)@[User::MyVariable]

Comment: Why is it not as simple as using an Execute SQL task to populate a SSIS variable with NewId()?

Comment: @Tab, it is that simple, and it is the solution I have implemented. However, I am wondering of a way to do this within SSIS for my own knowledge.

Comment: @MiguelH, how do I populate User::MyVariable with a GUID value?

Comment: To me, an execute SQL task IS "within SSIS", so can you be more exact about what you mean?

Comment: Sorry! My comment applied to a GUID I had previously generated. A script component would do the trick. See http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/create-guid-column-in-ssis.html

Comment: @Tab, what does one do in an environment without SQL Server - only has SSIS and text files to deal with.

Comment: SSIS doesn't exist without SQL Server, but assuming you mean you want a solution where you don't have to do a query to a database engine, you can use a script task as per my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem. To fix it, I created an SSIS "Composant Script" in which I created a "guid" output. The script VS C# code was the following :

```
Row.guid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Finally, I routed the output as a derived column into my database "OLE DB Destination" to generate a guid for every new entry.

Comment: More info on that in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17453385/717732

Answer (score 2):

Simply do it in an Execute SQL Task.

- Open the task
- Under General -> SQL Statement, enter your query `Select NewID() MyID` in the "SQLStatement" field
- Under General -> Result Set, choose "Single row"
- Under Parameter Mapping, Enter your User::myID in Variable Name, "Input" as direction, 0 as Parameter Name, and -1 as Parameter Size
- Under Result Set, enter "MyID" for your Result Name and type the variable in Variable Name

-Click OK

Done. Note that "MyID" is a value you can choose. EDIT: "User::myID" corresponds to the SSIS variable that you create.